# Error hdiutil: create failed - File exists -> but the file does not exist until this command fails

Tags: macos, disk-utility, dmg, nfs, hdiutil

Trying to create a .dmg file on an NFS share.

```
    % rm -f store.dmg && ls -l store.dmg
    ls: store.dmg: No such file or directory
    % hdiutil create -size 300g -fs APFS -volname Temp store.dmg || ls -l store.dmg
    hdiutil: create failed - File exists
    -rw-r--r--  1 risner  wheel  0 Sep 13 22:44 store.dmg
```

Disk Utility also fails with a file exists error.

I can read and write files on the NFS share fine. No issues. The mount in vifs is as such:

`192.168.40.10:/store /System/Volumes/Data/Store nfs rw,resvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc,noatime`

Still not working directly on the NFS, but bmike suggested I create it locally and move to the NFS share. I created a sparse bundle by adding `-type SPARSE` to the `hdiutil` and moved the sparse image to the NFS share. I can read/write files with the image open.

Why can I not directly create on the NFS share?

macOS 12.4 on M1 Mac Mini 8Gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround for the issue, but not a resolution. This allows me to use the image on the NFS share, but I still can't create it directly on the NFS share.

```
% hdiutil create -size 300g -type SPARSE -fs APFS -volname Temp ~/store
created: /Users/risner/store.sparseimage
```

I then copy the local file `/Users/risner/store.sparseimage` to the NFS share and mount.

Comment: Apple now is 100% in on smb shares, is there a reason you need nfs? Often there is, but I’ve had better support using smb on recent os. Nothing is as good or reliable as proper AFP share support, sadly. Especially for disk images and storing native files natively.

Comment: 10gbe with 9000 byte packets on a 900 tb file store. In tested, the performance was untenable with samba.

Comment: Without a good controller you may need to revamp the setup. Pegasus pro has stepped up with a tie ring option and I haven’t tested some of the newer storage vendors, but a few have compelling performance for video storage specifically for 8k footage https://www.promise.com/Products/Pegasus

Comment: Locked in on zfs data store, so changing away would have a ton of resistance. The true fix will be ordering a max mini M2 with 1TB